# Transform table to 0 and 1 for a given threshold

Tags: r, transform

I have a table (t1) as follows:

```
t1 <- array(1:20, dim=c(10,10))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11    1   11    1   11    1   11    1    11
 [2,]    2   12    2   12    2   12    2   12    2    12
 [3,]    3   13    3   13    3   13    3   13    3    13
 [4,]    4   14    4   14    4   14    4   14    4    14
 [5,]    5   15    5   15    5   15    5   15    5    15
 [6,]    6   16    6   16    6   16    6   16    6    16
 [7,]    7   17    7   17    7   17    7   17    7    17
 [8,]    8   18    8   18    8   18    8   18    8    18
 [9,]    9   19    9   19    9   19    9   19    9    19
[10,]   10   20   10   20   10   20   10   20   10    20
```

I want to transform this table to either 1 or 0.  If the cells number is >5, we give it a 1, if the cells number is <5 or = 5, we give it a 0.  Thus after transformation, table t1 will become the followings:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0   1    0   1    0    1    0    1    0    1
 [2,]    0   1    0   1    0    1    0    1    0    1
 [3,]    0   1    0   1    0    1    0    1    0    1
 [4,]    0   1    0   1    0    1    0    1    0    1
 [5,]    0   1    0   1    0    1    0    1    0    1
 [6,]    1   1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1   1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [8,]    1   1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [9,]    1   1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[10,]    1   1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Which commands should I used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use an `ifelse()` statement:

```
ifelse(t1 > 5, 1, 0)
```

Since a statement like `t1 > 5` will result in a matrix of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and since R treats `TRUE` as "`1`" and `FALSE` as "`0`", for this particular transformation, you could also do:

```
(t1 > 5)+0
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [3,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [4,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

Comment: An even slightly faster solution is to use explicit conversion: `fasterFun <- function(x) {y <- x>5; storage.mode(y) <- "numeric"; y}`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't timed it, but an alternative to `ifelse`  is just to use a conditional statement.

`foo <-  bar < 5`
Oh, dang,  Julius  went and beat me to it by 10 seconds.